# Working with XML Document using WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have created a WCFService Library in which I want to insert and get the data from XML.

My IService:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void InsertData(string Name, string Email, string Message);
    }   
}
```

My Service class:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq; 
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void InsertData(string Name, string Email, string Message)
    {
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DataFile.xml"));
        xmldoc.Element("root").Add(
            new XElement("User",
                new XAttribute("Name", Name),
                new XAttribute("Email", Email),
                new XAttribute("Message", Message)));
        xmldoc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("DataFile.xml"));
    }
} 
}
```

I am very new to WCF. When I run this and invoke my `insert()`, the following exception comes:

[image]

Comment: Set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to `true` at  `serviceDebug` node in your Web.config file to see where the exception was raised.

Comment: @Fdooch it is false already..

Comment: Oops, misprint. Not `false`, `true`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888816/why-wcf-cannot-be-invoked-in-wcftestclient

Comment: @Fdooch the same error is coming after setting the value to true

Comment: @DhavalPatel it is defined already in my App.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you include MessageLogging and Tracing and see what happens?

Comment: Where do i enable this?

Comment: Right click on  Service App.config file,choose Edit WCF Configuration,select Diagnostic and then turn on MessageLogging and Tracing(put trace level on verbose). When you're done, then in visual studio developer command prompt type svctraceviewer and navigate (File->Open) to path where you saved your service.You'll have there two files,app_tracelog and app_messages.You'll see here what is going on with your service,what you're sending and so on.Hope it will help...